# How to display a image file from cache directory file:/// using img html tag in ionic 4?

Tags: file, cordova, ionic4, filepath

I'm trying to display an image from photo library. It returns me, `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.mobile/cache/20200306_121224.jpg`

HTML tag `<img src="file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.mobile/cache/20200306_121224.jpg"/>` is not valid.

**Source code:**
*.ts file*

```
const cameraOptions = {
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      correctOrientation: true
    }
      this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {
        if(imageData){
          this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imageData).then(filePath => {
            resolve(filePath);
            //filePath variable is 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.mobile/cache/20200306_121224.jpg'
          }).catch(err => console.log(err));

        }
      }, (err) => {
        var error = JSON.stringify(err)
        reject(error);
      })
```

**Source code:**
*.html file*

```
<img [src]="item.FileURI" />
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
resolve(filePath);
```

with

```
resolve((<any>window).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(filePath))
```

source: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-display-image-using-file-uri/84977/25